# Error: Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am working on the Google Cloud Platform. I created an instance named sudbury4361.
When I power on the instance sudbury4361 and connect to SSH an error message is displayed after 4-5 mins.
How do I resolve this?

[image]
[image]

I expect the sudbury4361 terminal to open.

Comment: If my answer does not solve your problem, edit your question with details on the debugging steps and the results that you have tried.

Comment: I did the above steps I added the firewale rule and the other steps given below still I am unable to open the terminal. It displays : ERROR - failed to lookup instance

Comment: When you have problems using the GUI, try the CLI instead. The error messages might be more informative.

Comment: I added the rule with the CLI itself ; The error message displays - ERROR 4047 Failed to lookup instance.

Comment: I meant to use the CLI to SSH into the instance.

Answer (score 0):

If your VM instance does not have a public IP address, then you must configure a firewall rule to allow IAP.

The following CLI command will create the firewall rule:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-ssh-ingress-from-iap \
  --direction=INGRESS \
  --action=allow \
  --rules=tcp:22 \
  --source-ranges=35.235.240.0/20
```

You might also need to grant the user permission to use IAP. Replace `EMAIL` with the user's email address used for Google Cloud authentication. Replace `PROJECT_ID` with the Project ID.

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding PROJECT_ID \
    --member=user:EMAIL \
    --role=roles/iap.tunnelResourceAccessor

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding PROJECT_ID \
    --member=user:EMAIL \
    --role=roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1
```